# Android- Select an item of a GridView programmatically?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to perform a click on an item after `setAdapter()` method.

Consider if you have declared and initialized a **Button** in your **Activity** globally then you can perform a click on it programmatically from any scope of that activity and the listener will work. I want something similar like that, to be able to  perform a click on any item of my **GridView**.

So far i have tried all of the below methods one by one but none of them seems to work, i tried different stack questions but not even a single answer worked for me.
      `iconsGrid.setSelection(2);`, 
      `iconsGrid.setSelected(true);`, 
      `iconsGrid.performClick();`, 
      `iconsGrid.performItemClick(iconsGrid, 2, 2);`,
      `iconsGrid.performItemClick(iconsGrid, 2, iconsGrid.getItemIdAtPosition(2));`,

```
//Activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Integer[] resource_icons = { 
            R.drawable.ic_attachment,
            R.drawable.ic_attachment,
            R.drawable.ic_attachment,
            R.drawable.ic_attachment,
            R.drawable.ic_attachment,
            R.drawable.ic_attachment };

    GridView iconsGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_icons);
    IconGridAdapter iconAdapter = new IconGridAdapter(this, resource_icons);
    iconsGrid.setAdapter(iconAdapter);
   /*
    * I want to perform a click here
    */
}

//Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater li;
    View grid;
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        li = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        grid = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell_imageview, parent, false);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return grid;
}
```

Comment: what you want to achieve by selecting programmatically may be we can find another way?

Comment: i want to achieve selection, like when a user press any item in the gridView it gets highlighted with the default selector

Comment: gridView.performItemClick(gridView, 3, gridView.getItemIdAtPosition(3)). Reference: http://mantascode.com/android-how-to-programmatically-click-select-tap-a-listview-item/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK let's do this

declare one field in your adapter say

```
private int selectedPosition=-1;
```

now create a setter for this

```
private void setSelectedPosition(int position)
{
selectedPosition=position;
}
```

Now in your getView method

```
if(position==selectedPosition)
    {
    grid.setSelected(true);

    //OR

    grid.setBackgroundColor(<Some Color>);
    }
```

Now after setting the adapter

```
adapter.setSelectedPosition(<your desired selected item position>);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. `notifyDataSetChanged` is the key here i believe.

Answer (score 3):

In the xml file inside GridView just add `android:listSelector="@drawable/your_selector"`
after adding this line if you code like -

```
gridView.setSelection(POSITION); //position starts from 0
```

It will highlight that particular item.

and for perform click use -

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                 //do whatever you want to do
        }
});
```